# How to prevent my laptop from black screen when lid is closed?

Tags: windows, laptop, vnc

- I've checked the power settiings and selected "Do nothing" option. However, when I close the lid of my notebook, the monitor changes black and my VNC connect is off. How do I stop the magnetic lid from turning my screen black？

Comment: So you are looking to keep your VNC connection active once the lid is closed? What software are you using?

Comment: @Anaksunaman I use tightVNC and Anydesk, NoMachine, Teamviewer. All of them except NoMachine stop working after I close the lid.

Comment: At the worst, open the case, and add a switch in series with the reed-switch lid sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have in the past experienced Windows OS **completely ignoring power settings** as configured from the frontend user space.  At that time, the solution was to enforce power setting through `gpo` instead; if you don't have Pro Edition, refer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1543923/how-to-create-a-local-windows-10-home-account-without-login-privileges/1543943#1543943) for Home Edition.

Comment: Thanks you! I've got my group policy on. How to set it to meet my need？

Comment: There are many resources online, [here's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/managing-power-with-group-policy-part-1-of-3) an example.  Let me know if you need any additional assisstance.